# Jekyll collections in subdirectory and Ghpages

Tags: php, jekyll, liquid

A newbie question here. I have a following directory scheme for the project:

```
- index.md
- page1.md
- page2.md
- pages/
  - collection/
    - item1/
      - item1.md
    - item2/
      - item2.md
  - item3/
    - item3.md
```

How could I display all the items from collection and item3? The point is that the collection is into a subdirectory.

Thanks in advance